# Turning Dictionary into CSV format

Tags: python, python-3.x

My output currently looks like this:

```
[{'date': '20140206', 'exchange': 'cme', 'total_bytes': '15400000'},
{'date': '20140206', 'exchange': 'phlx', 'total_bytes': '14100000'},
{'date': '20140206', 'exchange': 'phlx', 'total_bytes': '13800000'},
{'date': '20140207', 'exchange': 'cme', 'total_bytes': '15800000'},
{'date': '20140207', 'exchange': 'cme', 'total_bytes': '14200000'},
{'date': '20140207', 'exchange': 'phlx', 'total_bytes': '24100000'}]
```

But I need it to look more like this:

```
date,exchange,total_bytes
20140206,cme,15400000
20140206,phlx,27900000
20140207,cme,30000000
20140207,phlx,24100000
```

As of right now I have multiple lines for the same date, I would like to group them so that there are no duplicate entries. IE. only one phlx entry for the 7th. (adding both values of bytes)

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import pprint

endresult = []

# write csv_input to a csv file
with open('csv_input.csv','w') as file:
    for line in csv_input:
        file.write(line)

# manipulate text - remove the 0001 from the host name to get just the initials - ex. cme
text = open("csv_input.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace("0001", "")
x = open("csv_input.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()

# read csv file created and add column names
with open('csv_input.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        endresult.append({
            'date': row['date'],
            'exchange': row['host'],
            'total_bytes': row['bytes']})
#print(row)

with open('last.csv', 'w', newline='') as txt_file:
    fieldnames = ['date','exchange','total_bytes']
    csv_dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(txt_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_dict_writer.writeheader()
    for result in endresult:
        csv_dict_writer.writerow(result)

pprint.pprint(endresult)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number libraries shipped with Python that can help here.

- [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) efficiently extras values for a sort key.
- [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will group iterated lines by similar keys.
- [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?#csv.DictReader) and [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?#csv.DictWriter) to reference CSV data by named columns.

Note `input.csv` below is your original CSV data.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

# Build a sort key by primary/secondary sort value
sorter = itemgetter('date','host')

# Read all the data
with open('input.csv','r',newline='') as fin:
    r = csv.DictReader(fin)
    data = sorted(r,key=sorter)

# build output lines grouped by the sort key
lines = []
for (date,host),group in groupby(data,sorter):
    lines.append({'date' : date,
                  'host' : host[:-4],
                  'total_bytes' : sum(int(data['bytes']) for data in group)})

# generate output
with open('output.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
    w = csv.DictWriter(fout,fieldnames='date host total_bytes'.split())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(lines)
```

output.csv:

```
date,host,total_bytes
20140206,cme,15400000
20140206,phlx,27900000
20140207,cme,30000000
20140207,phlx,24100000
```

Also, if your input data is already sorted appropriately, the code can be simplified to skip reading the entire data into memory and sorting it and process line-by-line instead.  Reading the whole file into memory could be impractical for a large amount of data.

Note the use of `.writerow()` which takes a single `dict` vs. `.writerows()` which takes a `list` of `dict`.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

sorter = itemgetter('date','host')

with open('input.csv','r',newline='') as fin, \
     open('output.csv','w',newline='') as fout:

    r = csv.DictReader(fin)
    w = csv.DictWriter(fout,fieldnames='date host total_bytes'.split())
    w.writeheader()

    for (date,host),group in groupby(r,sorter):
        w.writerow({'date' : date,
                    'host' : host[:-4],
                    'total_bytes' : sum(int(data['bytes']) for data in group)})
```

Answer (score 0):

- Read in your original csv file as `'test.csv'`
- Group similar `'date'` & `'exchange'` values using a defaultdict, with `'total_bytes'` added to a list.
- Split the keys and values out into a list of lists, and sum `'total_bytes'`
- Write the list of lists to a csv file.

```py
from collection import defaultdict
import csv

# read the csv
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = list(csv.DictReader(f))

# extract and group information from data
dd = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
    date, proc, _, _, tb = d.values()  # extract the values of interest
    proc = proc.split('_')[0]
    dd[f'{date}_{proc}'].append(tb)


# add dd keys to a list, sum dd values and add to the list
csv_list = [['date', 'exchange', 'total_bytes']]
for k, v in dd.items():
    d, e = k.split('_')
    tb = sum(map(int, v))
    csv_list.append([d, e, tb])


# write the list of list to a file
with open('new_csv.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerows(csv_list)

# view of csv file
date,exchange,total_bytes
20140206,cme,15400000
20140206,phlx,27900000
20140207,cme,30000000
20140207,phlx,24100000
```

### If you're not allowed to use any imports

```py
# read in the file
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = [row.strip().split(',') for row in f.readlines()]

# add list values of interest from data to a dict
dd = dict()
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    if i > 0:
        date, proc, _, _, tb = d
        proc = proc.split('_')[0]
        key = f'{date}_{proc}'
        if not dd.get(key):  # if the key doesn't exist
            dd[key] = [tb]  # create the key-value pair
        else:  
            dd[key].append(tb)

# add dd keys to a list, sum dd values and add to the list
csv_list = [['date', 'exchange', 'total_bytes']]
for k, v in dd.items():
    d, e = k.split('_')
    tb = sum(map(int, v))
    csv_list.append([d, e, tb])

# write the list of list to a file
with open('new_csv.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerows(csv_list)
```